# See image coverage for each date while doing machine learning to detect objects in NAIP HR images

Tags: google-earth-engine, naip

I am new to Google Earth Engine.  I want to write a machine learning to detect objects in [NAIP HR images](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/USDA_NAIP_DOQQ) over all images (i.e. over the entire continental USA) for all years.  I know I can run the script below I can see the image. But how can I figure out which dates are available and visualize which area each date covers?

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('USDA/NAIP/DOQQ')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2011-01-01', '2018-12-31'));
var trueColor = dataset.select(['R', 'G', 'B']);
var trueColorVis = {
  min: 0,
  max: 255,
};
Map.setCenter(-73.9958, 40.7278, 15);
Map.addLayer(trueColor, trueColorVis, 'True Color');
```

Comment: One question per Question, please, as per the [Tour].

Comment: My bad, I fixed it

Answer (score 1):

You enter your asset id in the search box in the code editor and read up on the asset: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/USDA_NAIP_DOQQ

> NAIP projects are contracted each year based upon available funding
> and the imagery acquisition cycle. Beginning in 2003, NAIP was
> acquired on a 5-year cycle. 2008 was a transition year, and a
> three-year cycle began in 2009.
>
> NAIP imagery is acquired at a one-meter ground sample distance (GSD)
> with a horizontal accuracy that matches within six meters of
> photo-identifiable ground control points, which are used during image
> inspection.

If you need to track dates per pixels, you can add a date band. The below script uses fractional year. Inspect a pixel and you see the acquisition dates. The script also massages the collection a bit, as it isn't homogeneous.

```
// All images in the collection doesn't have the same bands.
// This create a dummy image with all bands masked out.
var bandNames = ['B', 'G', 'R', 'N']
var maskedBands = ee.Image(
  bandNames.map(function (bandName) { // Client-side iteration
    return ee.Image().rename(bandName)
  })
)

var c = ee.ImageCollection('USDA/NAIP/DOQQ')
  .filterBounds(Map.getBounds(true))
  .map(function (image) {
    var date = image.date()
    var fractionalYear = ee.Image(
      date.get('year').add(date.getFraction('year'))
    ).float().rename('date')
    return image
      .addBands(maskedBands) // Fill in missing bands
      .select(bandNames) // Remove masked bands that had actual data
      .uint8()
      .addBands(fractionalYear)
  })
  
Map.addLayer(c.select('date'), null, 'dates', false)
Map.addLayer(c.median(), {bands: 'R,G,B', min: 0, max: 250}, 'RGB')
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/45cfb9745c5a18dc240a8017dc3f896d

Comment: From what I read there, I see it is every 3 years, but I need to know date and time, so I can figure out the tidal level for that location on that day and that time of the day

Comment: In what format do you need this information? An image with dates?

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you. That is not printing a list (text format) with dates and time available for that area. how can I get that please?